# Safari Push notification is not working

Tags: safari, apple-push-notifications, safari-push-notifications

I have been trying Safari push notification. I followed the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NotificationProgrammingGuideForWebsites/PushNotifications/PushNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013225-CH3-SW1).

Downloaded Apple intermediate Certificate [AppleWWDRCA.cer](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer). Exported my website provisioning profile as p12. To create the push Package used ruby package [push_package](https://rubygems.org/gems/push_package)

It created a package zip and it contains all the details that we needed - icon.iconset, manifest.json, signature and website.json.

When I request permission it successfully retrieves all data and gives me token.

But the real problem is when I try to send notification from a PHP script or APN tester its not receiving in the safari. The `v1/logs` getting called instead with some circular Json object.

Have no idea what to do next. can anyone please help ??

And one more thing I found is, in the logs  `SafariNotificationAgent (unknown version)`

Comment: Try using a service like Pushpad: it has a PHP library and given the cert it  generates the APNS package for you

Comment: Thanks for reply @collimarco ... Actually I am trying it my self... I am getting token.. but notification is not coming to safari... Its something related to the certificates.. Or I don't know whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

The error was in payload that I used.

It should be like:

```
 {
    "aps":{
          "alert":{
                   "title":"Hi there",
                    "body":"How are you",
                    "action":"viewed"
                  },
         "url-args":[""]
        }
 }
```